# Burninate request: [getstring]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

I was perusing the java tag today and noticed a tag I had not seen before, [getstring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/getstring). The question was referring to a `getString()` method.

I clicked on the tag and noticed that while it was somewhat java-centric (though there were a few C# questions), the references to a `getString()` method were all over the place as far as the libraries and APIs where this method was found. In addition, the average quality of the questions was sub-par.

I would like to propose that this tag is removed as I don't think it adds any extra context or value to tagged questions. Thoughts?

Comment: Burn it to the ground :]

Comment: Thanks for posting this request and allowing the community to weigh in! Please note that burninating a tag is the process of carefully moderating a specific piece of Stack Overflow (please think twice before doing tag-only mass edits, as they can be counter-productive); once the community reaches a consensus, burnination can proceed. For more info, see [What is the process for burninating tags?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324070).

Comment: This tag seems to have too many questions for being removed manually. We should let a moderator kill it with fire.

Comment: `Sorry, we no longer [getstring]s from this tag`

Comment: @dorukayhan only 105 ... SOCVR handled tags with way more questions. See our priority list [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/493425/burninate-priority-list)

Answer (score 2):

I agree, burn it. When you click on a tag, you should already know clearly what you are getting into. If the tag was [boy-bands], you'd know what will be there, and what will not, before you even click the link. The tag [getstring] doesn't have that clarity.

Answer (score 0):

1. no tag guideline
2. no following users
3. no specific technology that this tag refers to. as OP already mentioned it's mostly java, (but java can also refer to many unrelated uses such as android, web applications, games etc..), but I've also seen some python and PHP questions in there....

burn it!